# Encountering stale state when trying to pass state to sibling component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm building a simple to do list, and the code I'm trying to execute here is that when each task is clicked ('Task' component), it updates the parent state ('taskEdit') with the current task object. When taskEdit changes, a useEffect would run to re-render the whole component so that the parent can pass that object to another component ('EditTask' component) which is a modal that allows the user to edit the task, AND setEditModalVisible(true) would be run so that the Edit Task modal can be shown.

However, the issue is that when I do this, the 'EditTask' component renders with the previous state.

I.e. I click task A, and then Edit Task renders with an empty task object ({}), i.e. the initial state.

Then I click task B, and then Edit Task renders with the task A object.

Code is below. Any help is much appreciated!

**Parent Component - taskEdit state is initialized here, and setTaskEdit is passed to the child Task component. When it's updated, I intend to pass the updated taskEdit state to the Edit Task component**

*When I press the task, in addition to updating the task object, it would update taskEditTrigger to true, which would allow the setEditModalVisible to continue - then I'd set it to false so that any further renders wouldn't trigger editModalVisible*

```
  const [editModalVisible, setEditModalVisible] = useState(false);
  const [taskEditTrigger, setTaskEditTrigger] = useState(false);
  const [taskEdit, setTaskEdit] = useState({});
  
  useEffect(() => {

    if (taskEditTrigger) {
      setEditModalVisible(true)
      setTaskEditTrigger(false)
    } else {
      setTaskEditTrigger(false)
    }
  }, [taskEdit]);

const renderItem = ({ item }) => (


    <Task
      item={item}
      setTaskEdit={setTaskEdit}
      setTaskEditTrigger={setTaskEditTrigger}
    />
  );

  return (
      <View>
        <FlatList
          data={toDos}
          renderItem={renderItem}
        />
      <EditTask
        item={taskEdit}
        editModalVisible={editModalVisible}
        setEditModalVisible={setEditModalVisible}
      />
      </View>
```

**Task Component - on pressing the task component, I intended to update the taskEdit state in the parent component with the current task**

```
const Task = ({ item, setTaskEdit, setTaskEditTrigger })

    const onPressTask = () => {

        console.log(item.text)
        console.log('Task is rendering')

        if (item.isComplete) {
            setIsTaskCompleteAlertVisible(true)
        } else {
            setTaskEdit(item)
            setTaskEditTrigger(true)
        }             
    };

  return (
      <View>
           <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPressTask}>
               <Text>{item.text}</Text>
           </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>

Export default memo(Task, (prevProps, nextProps) => {
          If (prevProps.item.id  === nextProps.item.id &&

          prevProps.item.text  === nextProps.item.text)

          {

          return true

          }

          return false

})
```

**Edit Task Component - I then intended to pass the item={taskEdit} into the Edit Task component to show the relevant task information **

```
function EditTask({  
        item, editModalVisible, setEditModalVisible}) {
           
console.log(item)

const [editingText, setEditingText] = useState(item.text);

   const onPressEditTask = () => {
      setEditModalVisible(false)
      setTaskEdit({})     
    };

    return (
 <Modal visible={editModalVisible}>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPressEditTask}>
      <Text>{editingText}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
 </Modal>
```

Comment: This code is a bit convoluted, simplifying might help. For example, why do you have taskEditTrigger? Why not just use editModalVisible directly?

Comment: oh that was because I was trying to avoid triggering setEditModalVisible on a first render.  I've added some context on this in the description!

Comment: Are you using Modal from react-native? Shouldn't it be `visible` not `isVisible`? https://reactnative.dev/docs/modal#visible. I tried reproducing, and I don't see the problem you described: https://snack.expo.dev/pCtAG_kft

Comment: There are a few other issues here but I will get to them if I answer. Could you post the full EditTask component? It's odd that its stale -- I suspect there's some state duplication there not shown, or the fields within the modal may not be properly wired in.

Comment: Thanks @JBaczuk, I'm using react native modal. Also apologies for leaving this out but the task is memoized so that it doesn't rerender whenever home re renders.

Comment: Is there any other memoization?

Comment: @adsy no other memoization but is it something to do with the setTaskEdit that I'm passing to my memoized task component?

Comment: @JBaczuk thank you for doing up the Expo snack. I realized there was something in my code that was causing it - I was taking the text property from item and using it to set a new state object, editingText.

should have included that in the code, apologies. 

thanks Adsy as well for pointing out the state duplication.

is there a way I can use the values from item in a new state without having it be stale?

code added into:
snack.expo.dev/pCtAG_kft (as well as above code)

Comment: As a side note, whenever I press EditTask to dismiss the modal, clicking on the same task to pop up the modal doesn't do anything (probably because the taskEdit state is still the same). I'm currently trying to figure that out

Comment: Feel free to post another question. Best to keep multiple questions separate and focused. A snack that shows the issue you are facing is ideal. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: okay, will post another. thanks for helping me with this!

Comment: @JBaczuk I changed the code and was able to resolve it. I put the setEditingText together with the setTaskEdit, so everything is now in sync. 

would you like to add an answer to this? or should I add this edit and the answer?

Comment: @LloydRajoo Great! You should answer your own question and document the fixes you made, and how it answered your question. It may help someone else down the road.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all the comments - found the reason for this issue.

I was able to lift the lift the taskEdit state from the Task component and pass it down from the parent component to EditTask successfully.

However, in EditTask I was updating the editingText state using the item.text property - and that was what was stale. When I updated the editingText state directly in Task and passed it by the same way to the Edit Task component, it was no longer stale.